# accessing an array of objects by specific index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several elements:

```
<span class="item">01</span>
<span class="item">02</span>
<span class="item">03</span>
```

I'm making an array of them:

```
let items = $(".item");
```

This return an array of *objects*

However, when I try to access one of them like this:

```
console.log(items[1]);
```

I'm not getting an object anymore, but the html output of the object:

```
<span class="item">02</span>
```

1. *Why* is this happening?
2. How can I get an object when accessing a specific index in the
       array?

Comment: What do you mean by object? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You are confusing what is printed into console as being html which it is not. `items[1]` is actually a span element. To prove it try `console.log(items[1].textContent);`

Comment: The console just outputs the element that way. `items[1]` does, in fact return a reference to the DOM node.

Comment: *This return an array of objects* No, it doesn't. It returns a custom "array-like" object, commonly referred to as a JQuery Wrapped Set. This custom object is endowed with all sorts of properties and methods that are vastly different from an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(items[1])` or `$(".item:eq(1)")` or `items.eq(1)`.

Comment: Or, the OP could just use the original code, which does exactly what he wants it to do.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The OP wants a JQuery object, `items[1]` is a `Node`.

Comment: I don't believe that is clear from the question. The way I read it, the OP is just confused about what he sees in the console.

Comment: @ScottMarcus All my examples return a JQuery object. Take a look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: @ScottMarcus Read the question again. Specifically *I'm not getting an object anymore, but the html output of the object*

Comment: I have read the question carefully. I interpret this to mean that the OP believes he is getting a string returned, rather than an DOM node.

Comment: *And how can I get an object when accessing a specific index in the array?* I'm not sure why you interpret this to mean how to get a *JQuery* object.

Comment: @ScottMarcus What else could it mean ? The only problem that I can deduce is that the OP was expecting a JQuery object and got a Node instead. Maybe he doesn't know exactly what a Node is but my answer surely fixes his problem.

Comment: As I said, I interpret the question to mean "Why am I getting a String, instead of a node?".

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are  many ways to get the output here are few examples

```js
$(function(){
    console.log($('.item:nth-child(2)').text());
    console.log($('.item').eq(1).text());
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span class="item">01</span>
      <span class="item">02</span>
      <span class="item">03</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is just fine. When writing to the `console`, there's always an implicit `.toString()` call that is made on the data and so what, or rather the way, you see your data printed to the console doesn't always truly represent what you are working with:

```js
let items = $(".item");
console.log(items[1].nodeType); // 1 = element node
console.log(items[1].nodeName); // SPAN
console.log(typeof items[1]);   // object
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="item">01</span>
  <span class="item">02</span>
  <span class="item">03</span>
```